# How can I stop RegEx from matching out side of the capture group?

Tags: regex

I am writing some regex to look for system passwords that might have been shared over chat.

The requirements of the passwords are:

- 12-24 characters
- Alphanumeric
- 1 Special charecter (either $ or #)
- Must start with a letter

I thought I had came up with a decent pattern but my RegEx is matching the rules anywhere in the line:

```
\b(?=[\S]+)(?=(?:[a-zA-z]))(?=(?:.+\d))(?=(?:.+[$#]))(?!=[\s]*)([A-Za-z\d$#]{12,24})
```

I think I am using my boundaries improperly, what am I doing wrong?

```
this is  RealPa$$word  and it doesn't matter that the number is all the way here 1 

this is RealPa$$word and it doesnt match because there is no number.
```

Thanks!

**Update**
Here is a link to the Regexr i am using to validate.

https://regexr.com/6cep8

Comment: this lookahead requires a number to be present somewhere before end of string:  `(?=(?:.+\d))`, which is why the line ending in 1 is matching, but the other one isn't. (not really sure which one you want to match or what your requirements are)

Comment: That's very clear, but it should be part of the question, preferably at the beginning. Questions should be self-contained and not require readers to read comments to understand them. Can you do that and then delete your comment? I've deleted mine and will delete this one as well. There is no requirement that the string contain at least one letter. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some superfluous assertions and groups. This `(?=[\S]+)` asserts a  non whitespace char to the right, but the character class at the end of the pattern `[A-Za-z\d$#]{12,24}` does not match a space so you can omit that one.

This assertion `(?!=[\s]*)` is also unnecessary as there can also no `=` being matched by the character class.

Also, for a match only, you don't need a capture group.

If you assert this right after the word boundary `[a-zA-z]` (Note that is should be `[a-zA-Z]`) then you can also match it.

If you don't want to match spaces, the `.+` should be more specific without matching spaces, like matching optional non digits without spaces and then matching a single digit `(?=[^\d\s]*\d)`

If you want to have a boundary at the right, the `\b` would not work as there is `$` and `#` in the character class. You might assert a whitespace boundary at the right instead to not get partial matches for the `[A-Za-z\d$#]{12,23}` part.

As you can match the first `[a-zA-Z]` the quantifier can be `{11,23}` instead of `{12,24}`

```
\b[a-zA-Z](?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?=[^\s$#]*[$#])[A-Za-z\d$#]{11,23}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h0pFCS/1)

Comment: Nice answer! Can you simplify (slightly) to `\b[a-zA-Z](?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[$#])[A-Za-z\d$#]{11,23}(?!\S)` and if passwords needn't start with a letter, to `\b(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[$#])[A-Za-z\d$#]{12,24}(?!\S)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks :-) That is also possible of course. I chose the negated character class option to prevent a little be of the backtracking from `\S*` as it matches first until the end, and then backtracks until the first occurrence of for example a digit. But for the OP your pattern might be an easier read.

Comment: Ah, good point about the backtracking, something that never crosses my mind, but should.